# JPA ManyToMany with a readonly view

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a ManyToMany relationship between a table (PROCESO) and a read only view (FUNCIONINTEGRADA). These are the two entities:
First entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PROCESO")
public class Proceso extends Auditable<Long> {
   
   /* other fields */
   @JoinTable(
        name = "PROCESO_RESP",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "IDPROCESO", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="IDRESPONSABLE", nullable = false)
    )
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<FuncionIntegrada> responsables=new ArrayList<FuncionIntegrada>();

  /* Getters and setters */
}
```

and the second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FUNCIONINTEGRADA")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class FuncionIntegrada extends Auditable<Integer> {

   /* other fields */

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "responsables")
   private List<Proceso> procesos;

   /* Getters and setters */
}
```

As you can see, the view has to be readonly (It's very important not to write in this view). How can I update a process and add a "responsables" list without writing in FUNCIONINTEGRADA? When I update a process I receive an exception because it can't write anything in the view (obviously).
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: (1) If `FuncionIntegrada` is supposed to be read-only, why put `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on `@ManyToMany`? (2) Please show us how you're trying to update `Proceso` by adding to `Proceso.responsables`, it should really work out the box

Comment: Thank you Crizzis!!! I've removed cascade = CascadeType.ALL and all works fine!!